# Comparing Strings in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Hello I am confused according to string comparison in sql.

```
select * from table where column1 = 'abc';
```

As I understand the string 'abc' is converted to a number let us pretend (1+2+3=6) for this example.

This means that

```
select * from table where column1 = 'cba';
```

will also have the same value 6. The Strings are not the same. Please enlighten me.

Edit: Because you think this is a joke.

"The character letter King is converted to a numeric representation. Assuming a US7ASCII database character set with AMERICAN NLS settings, the literal king is converted into a sum of its ordinal character values: K+i+n+g = (75+105+110+103=393)."

This is the exact text from a book that made me confused.

Comment: Oracle is getting pretty crazy these days...

Comment: Are you getting confused with implicit conversions, in which a predicate such as "some_number_data_type = '6'" requires that the '6' be converted from a string to a number?

Comment: You downvoted me. That book was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quote seems to be from page 31 of [chapter 9 of this OCA/OCP Oracle Database 11g All-in-One Exam Guide](http://www.ktipsntricks.com/data/ebooks/oracle/oca-ocp-11g/ch09.pdf). This appears to be incorrect (being kind), since if it worked like then `abc` and `cba` would indeed be seen as equivalent.

The [11gR2 SQL language reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements002.htm#sthref311) says:

> In binary comparison, which is the default, Oracle compares character
>   strings according to the concatenated value of the numeric codes of
>   the characters in the database character set.  One character is greater
>   than another if it has a greater numeric value than the other in the
>   character set.

The key difference is phrase 'the concatenated value', i.e. closer to what @JoroenMoonen demonstrated, where the numeric codes from the character set are pieced together; and not the sum of the values as the book showed.

But it would be misleading to think of the numeric codes for each character being concatenated and the resulting (potentially very long!) string representing a number which is compared. Taking those values, `abc` = `000001000001000001100100` = `266340`, and `cba` = `011001000001000000000100` = `6557700`. Just comparing 6557700 with 266340 would indeed show that `cba` is 'greater than' `abc`. But `cb` is also 'greater than' `abc` - `select greatest('abc', 'cb') from dual` - and if you do the same conversion you get `cb` = `0110010000010000` = `25616`, which as a number is clearly less than 266340.

I think it's actually better explained in the [equivalent 10gR1 documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/sql_elements002.htm):

> Oracle compares two values character by character up to the first
>   character that differs. The value with the greater character in that
>   position is considered greater. If two values of different length are
>   identical up to the end of the shorter one, then the longer value is
>   considered greater. If two values of equal length have no differing
>   characters, then the values are considered equal.

So, assuming ASCII, `c` (99) is greater than `a` (97), so it doesn't need to look at any further characters in either string. This can never see `abc` and `cba` as equivalent.

Anyway, you're quite right to be confused by the book's explanation.

Comment: Thank you for not calling me stupid and you are right about the book ;)

Answer (score 3):

you rather see it like this

```
    a= 00000100
    b= 00010000
    c= 01100100

    abc= 000001000001000001100100
    cba= 011001000001000000000100
```

Thus not the same